# Is there a name to $[R:I]$ in Ring Theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I was solving problems related to elementary Ring Theory and I came across this question:

> Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Define $$[R:I] = \{x\in R : rx\in I, \forall r\in R\}$$ Show that $[R:I]$ is an ideal of $R$.

Is there a name to $[R:I]$ ? If yes, how can I know more about it? It sounds interesting.

Comment: I’ve heard it been called a [colon ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient?wprov=sfti1#Geometric_interpretation)

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout Thank you but in a colon ideal (I : J) , both I and J are ideals whereas in (R : I) in the question, R is a ring and I is an ideal of it.

Comment: It is called *ideal quotient* for two ideals $I,J$ and it is allowed that, say, one ideal is $R$ itself. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient). And please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you very much. Helped me a lot.

Comment: I suppose you meant $[R:I]$, as in the duplicate. There the remark is:"*You have swapped the "numerator" and the "denominator" in your definition of what is sometimes called a colon ideal. The correct notation is $(:)=\{∈∣∈ \text{ for every } ∈\}$ as in wikipedia.*

Comment: @DietrichBurde no, I copied it exactly as in my book. Maybe it's a misprint.

Comment: It may just be another convention. With $[R:I]=(I:R)$ everything is fine, so no problem. So the name is, I think, "ideal quotient".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150742/discussion-between-struggling-mathematician-and-dietrich-burde).